# Why does Xcode think gsl::span needs two template arguments?

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, guideline-support-library

I'm currently getting familiar with GSL, and I wrote the following very simple example just to test out how `gsl::span` works. Xcode seems to have problems with it as you can see here:

[image]

This compiles and runs just fine, as it should, but at the same time Xcode thinks that `gsl::span` needs another template argument, which is quite strange. I've never seen any compiler or IDE give an actual **error** (not just a warning) and then compile just fine.

`gsl::span` can deduce the size of your array, so the second template argument wouldn't be necessary. If I change the argument type to `gsl::span<int,5>`, the errors will go away, but of course this is not really a solution.

Comment: I don't know gsl, but if the compiler accepts it, it should be a Xcode bug. Parsing C++ is hard.

Comment: `gsl::span` is supposed to be a safer replacement for `pointer, size` kinds of interfaces. I think it's an Xcode bug too, since I don't get any kinds of warning or errors with the same code in VS2015, not even from running the [core guidelines code analysis](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/03/c-core-guidelines-checkers-available-for-vs-2015-update-1/) on it.

Comment: Well, very much looks like a bug in the Xcode error thing then. As I said, parsing C++ is hard, even the compilers themselves don't get it right all the time. In general, there are ways to get inline assistance with a real compiler as backend btw, such as vim + ycm. If such a tool shows an error, at least the backing compiler will too.

Comment: Old question, but `gsl::span` has indeed two template parameters. The second one is the extent, which is either a positive number for spans of static size or `dynamic_extent` (I believe currently -1) with dynamic size spans (as in this example). And no, that parameter can not be deduced, but it is defaulted to `dynamic_extent`. Why Xcode throws an error, even though the second one has a default value I can't tell.